# how to compare two strings in javascript if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, string-comparison

I'm having trouble recalling how to compare these two strings in an if statement. What I'm string to do is check if my variable `compare` equals `page1` or `page2` if not, go to the else statement.

```js
var compare = "page3";

if (compare === "page1" || "page2") {
  document.body.innerHTML = "github url";
} else {
  document.body.innerHTML = "non-github url";
}
```

Comment: `compare === "page2" `? Seems like an odd question for you to have.

Comment: compare === "page1" || compare === "page2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if( ["page1", "page2"].includes(compare) ){...}
```

```js
var compare = "page3";

if( ["page1", "page2"].includes(compare) ) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "github url";
} else {
  document.body.innerHTML = "non-github url";
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach. In my case, `compare` can also be `page1_other`. Which, with this approach, would get wrongly validated.

Comment: @jbarradas I check your case `compare="page1_other"` and `includes` give false for this case - which is correct (according to OP question)

Answer (score 19):

You could check every option.

```
if (compare === "page1" || compare === "page2") {
```

Or you could use an array and check with an existential quantifier like [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) against, like

```
if (["page1", "page2"].some(a => a === compare)) {
```

```js
var compare = "page3";

if (compare === "page1" || compare === "page2") {
    document.body.innerHTML = "github url";
} else {
    document.body.innerHTML = "non-github url";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you have multiple things to check in an `if` condition, you must write each condition separate from the other. So, the test must be written as:

```
// If compare equals "page1" OR compare equals "page2"
if (compare === "page1" || compare === "page2") {
```

When you have a single variable that may contain many different values, using a `switch` statement can be more logical and more efficient since it only has to look up the value of the variable one time.

Also, **remember that strings are literals and "page1" does not equal "Page1"**. To make a comparison that is case-insensitive, you can force all the values to lower (or upper) case first and then check them against each other (as shown here):

```
switch (compare.toLowerCase()) {
    case "page1" :
        // Do work here
        break;
    case "page2" :
        // Do work here
        break;
    case "page3" :
        // Do work here
        break;
    default :
        // Do work here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.localeCompare(b)` is another cool way of comparing larger strings

```
function areEqual(a, b){


  if (a.length !== b.length) {
         return false;
  }

  return a.localeCompare(b) === 0;
}


if(areEqual(a,b)){...}
```